# Getting NA in Standard deviation

Tags: r

when i write mean it worked

```
mean(b1temp[1, ])
```

but for standard deviation, it returns NA

```
sd(b1temp[1, ])

NA
```

SO, I modified the function but still returns NA

```
sd(b1temp[1, ], na.rm=FALSE)

NA
```

my dataset contains only a row. Is this an issue?

Comment: You need at least 2 values to get the SD.

Comment: *"only a row"* or only a column? And it should be `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Only use `rstudio` tag if the problem is caused by the programm `rstudio`. You have problems with your R-code.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is incorrect subsetting of `data.frame` as in effect when you execute `b1temp[1, ]` you get only `1` number where the standard deviation is not defined. Which is the reason of getting `NA`.

By default `data.frame` data are organized by column, not by row. So to apply `sd` to your data you should use subsetting for the columns `bitemp[, 1]`.

Please see the code and simulation below:

```
b1temp <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

b1temp[1, ]
# [1] 1

mean(b1temp[1, ])
# [1] 1

sd(b1temp[1, ])
# [1] NA

sd(1)
# [1] NA

b1temp[1, ]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

sd(b1temp[, 1])
# [1] 3.02765
```